# Change font when using MacroButton placeholder in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros, formatting, ms-office

In MS word you can create a [placeholder field](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/UsingMacroButton.htm) by:

- Inserting a new field (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>)
- Typing `MacroButton NoMacro [Enter Text Here]` inside the brackets {}
- Then toggling it out of edit mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>)

It will do this:

[image: screenshot]

In my template, empty fields are highlighted in *blue*, but should turn *black* once filled in.

**Q**: Is there a way to change the font once someone has filled in a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it is possible.

Using `MacroButton` with `NoMacro` merely serves to conveniently highlight the entire text area with a single click.  As with any highlighted object in word, when you start typing, it deletes the selected portion and formats the new text based on the style of the leftmost element (which in this case is the field itself - even though it's not displayed).

To 'change' the styles, simply start off by highlighting the entire field and formatting however you'd like the result to end up. Then highlight just the text portion and format however you'd like the prompt to display.

When in edit mode, it should look like this:

[image: screenshot]